# Access issue in dd4t

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t, logging

I am getting the following error while using DD4T content delivery in one of my application. I have not provided any dd4t logging provider in my web.config and hence it is trying to write to event log but I am not able to understand where to provide the permissions and to which user.We cannot use log4net for logging due to some organizational constraints.

```
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JuggerNETFrameworkException: Exception occurred during configuration callback ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
 Cannot open log for source 'Content Delivery.NET'. You may not have write access. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied --- 
End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.OpenForWrite(String currentMachineName) at 
System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent(UInt32 eventID, UInt16 category, 
EventLogEntryType type, String[] strings, Byte[] rawData, String currentMachineName) at 
System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, 
Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData) at 
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type) at 
Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Jvm.EventLogger.WriteEntry(String entryMessage, 
EventLogEntryType type) at 
Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Jvm.ConfigurationHook.ConfigMethod(IJvmLoader loader, Int32 
when) at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level) at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader() at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init() at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject() at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init() at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_MethodPtr() at 
Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_Handle() at 
Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo) at Com.Tridion.Broker.Querying.Query..ctor() at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query.Query..ctor() at 
DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1.TridionPageProvider.GetContentByUrl(String Url) at 
DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.TryFindPage(String url, IPage& page) at
```

Answer (score 4):

This error means the windows event log source `Content Delivery.Net` is either not present or configured to not allow the application pool user write access.

The SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 installation sources (subfolder `Content Delivery\roles\deployer\dotNet\x86_64`) come with an `EventLogCreator.exe` tool which is designed to create the windows event log source; try running that with admin privileges on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

There are two log files you may have, dd4t log files by default it will be creating under `App_Data`, If you are using your own log files location make sure that folder has write permission for your website apppool.

`bin/config/logback.xml` you may configured to logs the broker Tridion ContentDelivery core logs. Make sure that you have your website apppool having write permission to that folder.