# Access denied Error on removing Tridion Ambient Framework

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, ambient-data-framework, iis7

We are facing one issue when we are trying to remove Tridion ambient framework from our Live website [since it doesn't need XPM].
**Stack trace for Error** :

---

[InvalidOperationException: Cannot open log for source 'Content Delivery.NET'. You may not have write access.]
   System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.OpenForWrite(String currentMachineName) +2057717
   System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent(UInt32 eventID, UInt16 category, EventLogEntryType type, String[] strings, Byte[] rawData, String currentMachineName) +360
   System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData) +557
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type) +30
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Jvm.EventLogger.WriteEntry(String entryMessage, EventLogEntryType type) +48
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Jvm.ConfigurationHook.ConfigMethod(IJvmLoader loader, Int32 when) +103
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level) +570

[JuggerNETFrameworkException: Exception occurred during configuration callback]
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level) +868
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader() +64
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init() +119
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject() +51
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init() +1652
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_MethodPtr() +61
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_Handle() +80
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo) +431

---

Also I've tried following options :
1) Giving rights to folder and [registery keys.](https://support.thycotic.com/kb/a220/giving-application-pool-access-to-event-log.aspx%0A) 
2) Ran SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 installation sources (subfolder Content Delivery\roles\deployer\dotNet\x86_64) come with an EventLogCreator.exe tool which is designed to create the windows event log source; try running that with admin privileges on the machine.
 as suggested  [here.](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/access-issue-in-dd4t)

Tridion Version : 2011 SP1

Regards,
Tarun Panwar

Comment: do you have ambient framework enabled in cd.. configs?

Comment: We've removed ambient framework from cd_config. Tridion suggestion is to create new wesbite from scratch, so currently going in that direction.